# .Net MVC 4 Google OAuth account association

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, dotnetopenauth, google-oauth

I'm trying to use DotnetOpenAuth to allow users to login via Google into my website.  This came pre-installed with the MVC 4 Website Application project.

Some of my users are complaining that they can successfully login via a Google OAuth request, but when they try from another machine (or at times another browser), it see's them as a new user.  It does not log them into their existing account.

I'm not sure if any code snippets would help debug the issue, but the entire site is available on github:

[MVC Site Code](https://github.com/jrmitch120/ChallengeBoard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was do to users mixing www.domain.com vs domain.com.  It would appear that different tokens are issued for each?

I am now using the following rewrite rule to route domain.com to www.domain.com

```
<rewrite>
     <rules>
          <rule name="Add WWW prefix" > 
               <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" /> 
               <conditions> 
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain\.com" /> 
               </conditions> 
               <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" /> 
          </rule> 
     </rules>
</rewrite>
```